# Disabling Ctrl+Win+Q on Windows

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using Ctrl+Win+Q to invoke [Slickrun](https://bayden.com/SlickRun/) for some time now.

**My Windows version is 1809 (OS Build 17763.439)**

Now all of a suddent Windows has stolen the shortcut for its own Quck Assist.

How do I disable it so that it is not popping up quick assist and invokes Slickrun?

Comment: Unlike your previous request, it does not appear that this can be disabled.

Comment: Oh I see :) thanks for that, I though it was a universal solution. I retracted it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using "Quick Assist" you can go Settings => Apps => Manage Optional Features  and uninstall "Microsoft Quick Assist".

Only way i know to disable "Quick Assist" keyboard shortcut key is disabling all "Win+X shortcuts" through gpedit.msc(User Configuration=> Administrative templates => Windows Components => File Explorer => Turn Off Windows + X hotkeys) .